# Form elements appear outside the form

Tags: html, css, forms

I render a form like this:

```html
<form action='/search' method='get' style='display: none'>
  <input name='q' type='search' />
  <input type='submit' value='Search' />
</form>
```

In the page source this piece appears like it is, but both Web Inspector and Firebug show it in the DOM tree like this:

```html
<form action='/search' method='get' style='display: none'></form>
<input name='q' type='search' />
<input type='submit' value='Search' />
```

Hence, the inputs are visible despite the `display: none` statement, and form submission doesn't work too.

Why is it so, any ideas? The mystery is even deeper: this form is rendered on two pages of the site, and on the other page it appears just as expected.

Answer (score 0):

The form should not be visible with display set to none. And its even working on one of your page so you are sure about the code. You need to check the code in other page. I guess you have pasted the code of the working form :)

Answer (score 0):

Create div and apply display:none to it. instead of form applying display none to form element